# Volatile Reads / Writes and Thread.MemoryBarrier Ordering

Tags: c#, thread-safety, memory-barriers

I'm trying to wrap my head around the subtleties around memory barriers and volatile reads/writes. I am reading Joseph Albahari's threading article here:

http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx

And stumbling on the issue of when a memory barrier is needed before a read/write and when it is needed after. In this section of code in the section "full fences", he puts a memory barrier after each write and before each read:

```
class Foo
{
  int _answer;
  bool _complete;

  void A()
  {
    _answer = 123;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 1
    _complete = true;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 2
  }

  void B()
  {
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 3
    if (_complete)
    {
      Thread.MemoryBarrier();       // Barrier 4
      Console.WriteLine (_answer);
    }
  }
}
```

He goes on to explain:

> Barriers 1 and 4 prevent this example from writing “0”. Barriers 2 and
>   3 provide a freshness guarantee: they ensure that if B ran after A,
>   reading _complete would evaluate to true.

**Question #1:** I have no problem with barriers 1 and 4, as it will prevent reordering across those barriers. I don't entirely understand why barriers 2 and 3 are necessary though. Can someone explain, especially considering how volatile reads and writes are implemented in the `Thread` class (explained next)?

Now where I really start to get confused is that this is the actual implementation of `Thread.VolatileRead/Write()`:

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static void VolatileWrite (ref int address, int value)
{
  MemoryBarrier(); address = value;
}

[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static int VolatileRead (ref int address)
{
  int num = address; MemoryBarrier(); return num;
}
```

As you can see, in contrast to the previous example, the built-in volatile functions place memory barriers before each write (instead of after) and after each read (instead of before). So if we were to rewrite the previous example with an equivalent version based on the built-in volatile functions, it would look like this instead:

```
class Foo
{
  int _answer;
  bool _complete;

  void A()
  {
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 1
    _answer = 123;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 2
    _complete = true;
  }

  void B()
  {
    if (_complete)
    {
      Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 3
      Console.WriteLine (_answer);
      Thread.MemoryBarrier();       // Barrier 4
    }
  }
}
```

**Question #2:** Are both Foo classes functionally equivalent? Why or why not? If barriers 2 and 3 (in the first Foo class) are needed to guarantee the value is written and the actual value is read, then wouldn't the `Thread.VolatileXXX` methods be kind of useless?

There are a couple similar questions on StackOverflow with accepted answers like "barrier 2 ensures the write to _complete isn't cached", but none of them address why `Thread.VolatileWrite()` puts the memory barrier before the write if that's the case, and why barrier 3 is needed if `Thread.VolatileRead()` put the memory barrier after the read yet guarantees an up to date value. I think that's what's throwing me off the most here.

**UPDATE:**

Okay so after more reading and thinking I have a theory and I updated the source code with attributes I think might be relevant. I don't think the memory barriers in the `Thread.VolatileRead/Write` methods are there to ensure "freshness" of the values at all, but rather to enforce the reordering guarantees. Putting the barrier after reads and before writes ensures that no writes will be moved before any reads (but not vice versa).

From what I have been able to find, all writes on x86 guarantee cache coherence by invalidating their cache line on other cores so "freshness" is guaranteed as long as the value is not cached in a register. My theory on the way `VolatileRead/Write` ensure the value is not in a register, which may be way off but I *think* I'm on the right track, is that they count on a .NET implementation detail where if they are marked `MethodImplOptions.NoInlining` (which as you can see above they are) then the value will need to be passed to/from the method instead of being inlined as a local variable and thus will have to be accessed from memory/cache instead of directly through a register, thus eliminating the need for an additional memory barrier after the write and before the read. I have no idea if that's the case, but that's the only way I can see it working properly.

Can anyone confirm or deny that this is the case?

Comment: Microsoft screwed this up pretty badly.  They fixed it with the Volatile class, [read the comment](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/volatile.cs,18).

Comment: @HansPassant As far as I can tell, the Volatile methods are faster with less ordering guarantees but otherwise the Thread methods still guarantee fresh reads and such. I updated my answer with my theory after some more digging - any additional comment about that? I'm trying to understand how the volatile read works with the memory barrier AFTER the read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't think the memory barriers in the `Thread.VolatileRead/Write` methods are there to ensure "freshness" of the values at all, but rather to enforce the reordering guarantees.

That's right.

> Putting the barrier after reads and before writes ensures that no writes will be moved before any reads (but not vice versa).

A full memory barrier has both acquire and release semantics, it prevents both previous memory accesses from being reordered to after the barrier and succeeding memory accesses from being reordered to before the barrier.

> Can anyone confirm or deny that this is the case?

You may be right about writes in Microsoft's .NET implementation in x86, but the same does not apply to reads.  The read could be reordered between previous accesses and the memory barrier, either by the JIT compiler (perhaps not with the no-inlining attribute) or by the CPU (even with the no-inlining attribute).

However, this shouldn't change what the running code sees, although the read might not see the *freshest* value.

```
int value = 0;
bool done = false;

// in thread 1
value = 123;
Thread.VolatileWrite(ref done, true);

// in thread 2
Thread.SpinUntil(() => Thread.VolatileRead(ref done));
Console.WriteLine(value); // guaranteed 123 due to the memory barrier
```

In other architectures with weaker memory models, the write can be reordered to after the succeeding memory accesses, and in the extreme case, it may not become visible to other threads until the next memory barrier.  With loops, this isn't much of a problem, though.

Anyway, my advise is to just not use `Thread.VolatileRead` and `Thread.VolatileWrite`.

Reads and writes to `volatile` fields, and the `Volatile.Read` and `Volatile.Write` methods provide the right semantics.

Although the `Volatile.Read` and `Volatile.Write` methods are implemented in C# just like the `Thread.VolatileRead` and `Thread.VolatileWrite`, the CLR replaces the methods with native versions with actual volatile read/write semantics.

Comment: I know memory barriers prevent both from being moved, but because of the way the `Volatile` methods are written, if you do a `Write` followed by a `Read`, the processor may still reorder them because there is no memory barrier between the two, hence it doesn't necessarily prevent reads from being moved before writes.

Comment: The documentation for `Thread.VolatileRead` states that it gets the most up to date value. Are you saying the documentation is incorrect?

In a loop it might not matter, but it may make a big difference in code that does a one time check if that's the case.

Comment: *"the processor may still reorder them because there is no memory barrier between the two"* -- Yes, but any possible outcome is allowed.  If the read is on the same variable, it'll have the correct value due to data dependency; if it's on a different variable, then (from the CLR spec) *"a conforming implementation is not required to provide a single total ordering of volatile writes as seen from all threads of execution."*  So, multiple volatile writes from multiple threads may happen in any order.

Comment: *"Are you saying the documentation is incorrect?"* -- Yes (and I'm not the only one, for what it's worth), or at least it depends on a definition of *freshness* that is not necessarily the *current* or *latest* at the time of the read instruction.  *"it may make a big difference in code that does a one time check"*  -- If you don't synchronize (or otherwise detect volatile changes), there's no correct outcome anyway.  What *correct* case do you have in mind that depends on such one time check?

Comment: I know it's allowed. You quoted "putting the barrier after reads and before writes ensures that no writes will be moved before any reads (but not vice versa)" and replied with stuff about memory barriers not allowing both memory accesses being reordered. We aren't in disagreement about anything, I'm just showing you how my statement was correct because it appeared as though you misunderstood what I was trying to say and were attempting to correct me in some way.

Comment: Also in terms of other architectures - if .NET was released on those, they would have different implementations of the `Thread.Volatile` methods to ensure the behavioral guarantees are met. I'm trying to understand why the current implementation "works", that's all. I think I got it now though. I think you're right on the single check vs looping thing as I can't think of any examples that would work without using `Interlocked` to synchronize a single access conditionally, so nevermind :)

Comment: *"it appeared as though you misunderstood what I was trying to say and were attempting to correct me in some way."* -- Please excuse me, I didn't intend to. *"if .NET was released on those, they would have different implementations of the `Thread.Volatile` methods to ensure the behavioral guarantees are met."* I don't know, there's .NET for ARM (e.g. Windows RT) and I believe the methods are untouched, but I have no way to check it myself right now (e.g. run ILDasm or ILSpy on that framework's assemblies, mscorlib, System, System.Core, etc.)

Comment: I think most implementations of ARM also guarantee cache coherence on writes so I don't think that's an issue, but correct me if I'm wrong.